# Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices - How to avoid deadlock?

Tags: c++, winapi, dllmain, loaderlock

### Background

I've read [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and understood what I can and can't do in [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now, say I have a visual studio 2013 solution containing many projects. each project generates different binaries/lib files.

Say I have some utility project, generating a lib file, used by all projects.

Now, this utility project, may define some generic functions that calls, for example, [LoadLibrary function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) which based on the link above is something that: *never perform the following tasks from within DllMain*

### Question

1. How can I implement a generic function, that "knows" that it can't use certain API because it is being called withing the scope of `DllMain` function?
2. Is it possible to access windows loader lock and by that disable certain calls or change function's algorithm if it is locked?

### Example

**Project Utility**

```
wstring GetUserName() // just an example!
{
   // do something including LoadLibrary call
}
```

**Project A**

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  _In_  DWORD fdwReason,
  _In_  LPVOID lpvReserved
)
{
   // calls Utility - GetUserName()
}
```

**Project B**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   // calls Utility - GetUserName()
}
```

While the call to function `GetUserName()` is perfectly fine in `Project B`, it is prohibited in `Project A`

I want to make mu solution smart in such way that I avoid such cases.

### Theoretical approach

```
wstring GetUserName() // just an example!
{
   if( IsLoaderLocked() )
      // do something excluding LoadLibrary call
   else
      // do something including LoadLibrary call
}
```

the `if( IsLoaderLocked() )` is not a real code, of course. Just an example of a condition I'd like to evaluate before calling "dangerous" API.

Comment: I have a feeling, that you messed things up. First of all, your 'utility' project generates `lib` file. Static libraries do not have anything like `DllMain()`. Also, `DllMain()` is not even required in DLLs. It is a very Windows-specific thing. Please, explain more about structure of your project and relationship between its components.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I've added an example.

Comment: It is possible to call `LoadLibrary` within `DllMain`. There is no problem as long as there is a well-understood dependency in order of DLL initialization. The matter with `LoaderLock` is that it is held implicitly, so if you also use your own locks - this may lead to deadlock. For instance, a typical mistake is to create a thread in a `DllMain` and wait for it, whereas that thread calls some API that implicitly calls `LoadLibrary` as well.

Comment: @valdo The above example is just an example :). whether or not _It is possible to call `LoadLibrary` within `DllMain`_ is not the **real** issue. eventually There are some operations, taking place in `Project Utility`, that are not allowed whiting `DllMain`. I'm trying to bulletproof my code to any deadlock that **may** occur.

Comment: Don't really understand why this question is flagged as "too broad". there must be a best practice approach to this generic issue.

Comment: If there is a best practice, it's 'don't create complex DllMain initializations. If you think you need one, think some more.'

Comment: @bmargulies. I 100% agree with _ 'don't create complex `DllMain`_ and I do think that this is the right thing to do. **However, the question still remains**. So, instead of bypassing the issue I'm trying to solve it, in the most elegant and robust way there is.